# Progress Dialog in SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, concurrency

I have a method register() that takes a lot of time to complete. So i've placed it in doInBackGround() of swingworker. In a meantime i want to display dialog that is modal and has indeterminate progressbar on it.

```
private void registerPopupItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    WaitDialog dialog = new WaitDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
    dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {


    });
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            register();
            return 0;
        }
    };
    dialog.dispose();   
}
```

But everything freezes. In debugger i see that regester() is not invoked. Where did i messed up? Any help would be appreceiteed! Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dialog.dispose is called after calling setVisible(true) on the *modal* dialog, so dispose may never be called. Instead have dispose called in the done override in the SwingWorker and call execute on the SwingWorker *before* calling setVisible(true) on the dialog.

Something like so (caveat, code not tested):

```
private void registerPopupItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    WaitDialog dialog = new WaitDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
    dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

    });
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            register();
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! it seems that register() cant be accessed or something.

Comment: @bunnyjesse112: then you've got a completely separate problem then the one posted above, and in code not shown. Consider asking a new question on SO and provide pertinent information regarding this problem including any error message texts. Also check out the scope of the register method.